# Special hyperbolic triangle

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Can we visualize from any book/report reference a spiky  curvilinear  triangle with each vertex angle zero and area (by Gauss-Bonnet theorem) $\pi a^2$ on  any surface of constant Gaussian curvature $K=-1/a^2$ in $\mathbb R^3 ?$

Can portions of it exist across cuspidal edges?

Comment: Look in Thurston's notes, one of the earlier chapters (I forget which one). The triangle cusps wrap around closed geodesics. A triangulation looks something like this. https://math.uchicago.edu/~dannyc/OUPbook/singular.png

Comment: Am afraid I cannot see the point.. Lines at center are visibly non- geodesic, more like level curves.

Comment: I think you cannot construct a real ideal triangle in euclidean 3d space , you can construct an triangle with one angle of 0 on a pseudo sphere ( the angle of 0 is far away from the cusp

Comment: *GB theorem cannot be visualized on the Beltrami pseudosphere for this case*... Right?

Comment: I would not say that ,just that you cannot construct an hyperbolic ideal triangle  in euclidean 3d space Gauss Bonnet with other angles (not more than one  zero) is I think possible